# Get a value of a button in the textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, calculator

I'm trying to build a calculator and I want to get the values of the clicked buttons in the textbox

this just an example how can I get the values of the clicked buttons here

```
<input type="text" name="" id="textfield" placeholder="Text" class="Text" readonly><br>
<button class="Y" value="Y"  onclick="">Y</button>
<button class="A" value ="A" onclick="">A</button>
<button class="S" value ="S" onclick="">S</button>
<button class="I" value ="I" onclick="">I</button>
<button class="R" value ="R" onclick="">R</button>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? show your code, and I am sure there are tons of answers  on SO for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can use javascript to handle this type of functionality . For Example :

```js
function appendValue(value) {
  var textfield = document.getElementById("textfield");
  textfield.value += value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="textfield" placeholder="Text" class="Text" readonly><br>
<button class="Y" value="Y" onclick="appendValue('Y')">Y</button>
<button class="A" value ="A" onclick="appendValue('A')">A</button>
<button class="S" value ="S" onclick="appendValue('S')">S</button>
<button class="I" value ="I" onclick="appendValue('I')">I</button>
<button class="R" value ="R" onclick="appendValue('R')">R</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to set value in button. [Check this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/py6zqdLf/26/)

Anyway, here's snippet for approach with button's value:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const input = document.getElementById("textfield");

let text = "";


buttons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    text = text.concat(btn.value)
        input.value = text;
}))
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="textfield" placeholder="Text" class="Text" readonly><br>
<button class="Y" value="Y"  onclick="">Y</button>
<button class="A" value ="A" onclick="">A</button>
<button class="S" value ="S" onclick="">S</button>
<button class="I" value ="I" onclick="">I</button>
<button class="R" value ="R" onclick="">R</button>
```